# Issue with the latest jquery colorbox v1.4.14

Tags: jquery, fancybox, colorbox

We have recently updated the jquery colorbox to its latest version v1.4.14. After the update, the fields(input, select) inside the jquery UI Modal Dialog/Fancy Box opened from within the colorbox looks like readonly. We are not able to edit/enter any text of the fields of Modal Dialog.

Below is the code We have used to open the colorbox and the fancybox(within colorbox):

```
$.colorbox({ href: '/Contact/Save/' + Id, width: "1200px", height: "450px", title: 'Loan & Borrow ', overlayClose: false, escKey: false, onLoad: function () { $('#cboxClose').hide() }, onComplete: function () { $('#cboxClose').show() } });

$.fancybox({
        'width': 100,
        'height': 100,
        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'speedIn': 600,
        'speedOut': 200,
        'overlayShow': true,
        'overlayOpacity': '0.9',
        'autoScale': false,
        'autoDimensions': false,
        'title': 'Quick Add',
        'titleShow': true,
        'titlePosition': 'over',
        'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
        'centerOnScroll': false,
        'href': '/Contact/_QuickAddLocation',
        'onComplete': function () {
            $("#fancybox-wrap").css({ 'top': '5px', 'bottom': 'auto' });
            $("#fancybox-content").css({ 'padding-top': '35px' });
        }
    });
```

It works fine with the jquery colorbox version v1.3.19. Do we have any workaround for the latest version v1.4.14? Please suggest.

Comment: check what is the `z-index` of the new colorbox; fancybox v1.3.x (the one I assume you are using) default is 1102. Then you may need to set colorbox's `z-index` lower than that or increase fancybox's `z-index`

Comment: We have 9999 as z-index for colorbox in latest and previous version and 10009 as z-index for fancybox. I have even changed the z-index of colorbox to 100, but still the same issue :(